# Can't Split work evenly between clients with a Server that handles multuple clients in c

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, server, client

i have written a server to handle multuple clients with threads.  The only problem is that even though I have locked the critical sections it wont split the work evenly between the clients.

Here is the Server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

void *con(void *);
int r, x, convr, convx, flag;
double sqrtr,doubler;
pthread_mutex_t var;

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    srand(time(NULL));
    r=rand();

    r=(r%(21474836146-2000000000))+2000000000;
    r=340;
    doubler=(double)r;
    x=2;
    convr=htonl(r);
    convx=htonl(x);

    sqrtr=sqrt(doubler);
    flag='p';

    int soc, clientsoc, *new, asize;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;

    soc=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(soc==-1){
        perror("Error creating socket");
    }

    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port=htons(7897);

    if(bind(soc,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server))<0){
        perror("Error binding socket");
        return 1;
    }
    if(listen(soc,5)!=0){
        perror("Error listening");  
    }
    int start='n';
    printf("Are you ready to start?  Don't continue until you have connected all the"
             " clients you with to use to the server.  (press y for yes)\n");
    start=getchar();
    while(start!='y'){
        printf("Are you ready to start?  Don't continue until you have connected all the"
             " clients you with to use to the server.  (press y for yes)\n");
        start=getchar();
    }
    asize=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while((clientsoc=accept(soc,(struct sockaddr *)&client,(socklen_t*)&asize))){
        pthread_t client_thread;

        new=malloc(1);
        *new=clientsoc;
        if(pthread_create(&client_thread,NULL,con,(void*) new)<0){
            perror("Error creating thread");
            return 1;
        }
        pthread_join(client_thread,NULL);
    }
    if(clientsoc<0){
        perror("Error accepting");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

//the handeler for a connection
void *con(void *socket){
    int soc=*(int*)socket;
    int flagtemp, flagtempconv;
    //what it will do here
    int rs;
    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&var);
        printf("Sending %d\n",r);
        if(write(soc,&convr,sizeof(convr))<0){
            printf("Failed to send");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Sending %d\n\n",x);
        if(write(soc,&convx,sizeof(convx))<0){
            printf("Failed to send");
            exit(1);
        }
        if(rs=read(soc,&flagtemp,sizeof(flagtemp))>0){
            flagtempconv=ntohl(flagtemp);
            printf("Received %d\n",flagtempconv);
            if(flagtempconv=='n')
                flag=flagtempconv;
            if(flag=='n'){
                printf("The numer %d is divisible by %d and is not prime\n",r,x);
                break;
            }else if(x>=sqrtr){
                printf("The number %d is prime\n",r);
                break;
            }
            x++;
            convx=htonl(x);
        } else if(rs==0){
            printf("Disconnected from client");
        } else if(rs<0){
            printf("Read error");   
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&var);
    }
    close(soc);
    exit(0);
}
```

Here is the client

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int r, x, convr, convx, flag, convflag, soc, mod;

    flag='p';

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    soc=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if(soc==-1){
        perror("Error creating socket");
    }

    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_port=htons(7897);

    if(connect(soc, (struct sockaddr*)&server,sizeof(server))<0){
        perror("Error connecting");
        return 1;
    }
    //put what the socket will do here
    while(1){
        if(read(soc,&r,sizeof(r))<0){
            printf("Error receiving\n");
        }
        convr=ntohl(r);
        printf("Received %d\n",convr);
        if(read(soc,&x,sizeof(x))<0){
            perror("Error receiving");
        }
        convx=ntohl(x);
        printf("Received %d\n",convx);
        mod=convr%convx;
        printf("%d mod %d = %d\n",convr,convx,mod);
        if(mod==0){
            flag='n';
            convflag=htonl(flag);
        }
        printf("Sending %d\n\n",flag);
        if(write(soc,&convflag,sizeof(convflag),0)<0){
                printf("Failed to send");
                return 1;
            }
    }
    close(soc);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this on multuple clients, one client does all the work.  The other client appears to have an error receiving the first message, and does not say whether it receives or does not receive the second.  Then it appears to receive the two integers I sent to it, only when it prints them out it does not convert them back from htonl(int).  Here is my out put I am getting for this program on the server and the first client and the second.  Also, the client that does all the work is always the first one i connect to the server with.  Also, please do not suggest to not use threads because I have to use threads for this.

Here is what the server does

> kyle@kyle-VirtualBox:/media/sf_cs_470$ ./lab4_server Are you ready to
>   start?  Don't continue until you have connected all the clients you
>   with to use to the server.  (press y for yes) y Sending 340 Sending 2
>
> Received 110 The numer 340 is divisible by 2 and is not prime

This is what the client does that does all the work

> kyle@kyle-VirtualBox:/media/sf_cs_470$ ./lab4_client Received 340
>   Received 2 340 mod 2 = 0 Sending 110
>
> Received 340 Received 2 340 mod 2 = 0 Sending 110
>
> Received 340 Received 2 340 mod 2 = 0 Sending 110

this is the client that is not working

> kyle@kyle-VirtualBox:/media/sf_cs_470$ ./lab4_client Error receiving
>   Received -924752754 Received -25296896
>   -924752754 mod -25296896 = -14064498 Sending 112

Thank you so much for helping me out.  Again, the goal is to split up the work as evenly as possible among the clients.

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]` with out first checking `argc` to assure the command line parameter actually exists.   When the command line parameter does not exist, output to `stderr` a USAGE message that shows the correct way to invoke the program, then immediately exit the program.  I.E. `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <param1>\n", argv[0] );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  2) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent) 3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  4) variable names should indicate `usage` or `content` (or better, both).  Names like `x` and `r` are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: regarding these two line: `r=(r%(21474836146-2000000000))+2000000000;
    r=340;`.   What is the code trying to do?   The code is calculating `r`, the overlaying that calculation with `340`.  It cannot be both values

Comment: this line: `while((clientsoc=accept(soc,(struct sockaddr *)&client,(socklen_t*)&asize))){ is not correct because the `accept()` function, on error, will return a `-1` and that error condition needs to be specifically checked,  otherwise the `-1` will satisfy the `while()` and it will enter the body of the `while()` loop

Comment: after successfully calling `malloc()`, any later exit/return should pass the pointer returned from `malloc()` to `free()` before returning/exiting

Comment: Your question asks how to get equal time for each client, BUT the server code ignores all further client connections until the processing for the current client is completed

Comment: when displaying an error message, like after a call to `write()`, the error message should be sent to `stderr`, not `stdout`, and it is also a very good idea to display the reason the OS thinks the function failed.  There is a specific function for that.  `perror()`.

Comment: the `read()` function can fail to get all the characters, so should loop, appending the read data, until the returned value is 0

Comment: these two line: `else if(x>=sqrtr){
                printf("The number %d is prime\n",r);` seems to be not correct.  Suggest re-researching the significance of the square root of a number being checked for prime.

Comment: the way the server is written and the way the server thread is written, the thread will not exit until an I/O error and the server will not move to the next client until the thread returns, When the error will occur is a undefined time,  So naturally, different amounts of time are taken for each client.

Comment: in the client code, the function `read()`, `write()`, `close()`  are not defined (because missing the statement: `#include <unistd.h>`)

Comment: regarding these lines: `if(soc==-1)
    {
        perror("Error creating socket");
    }`  there is absolutely no reason for the client to continue executing, so the last statement inside those brackets should be: `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`  Similar considerations for when a call to `read()` returns a value <0

Comment: functions in the `htonl()` family are for modifying items that are part of a IP packet header so they are in `internet` order.   That modification is completely unnecessary of the payload of the IP packets.

Comment: in the client, nothing in the header file `string.h` is being used, so that header file should not be included.   However, there are several places where the code should be calling `exit()`, perhaps with the `EXIT_FAILURE` parameter and that requires including the `stdlib.h` header file.

Comment: the client uses neither `argc` nor `argv[]`, so should use the signature for main() of `int main( void )`

Comment: Suggest keeping an array of thread IDs, do not call `pthread_join()` in the main processing loop,  (the server code can do that call just before exiting.)

Answer (score 1):

First: This is not a question about C. It's a question about POSIX threads, and about BSD sockets, among other things; but none of those things are part of the C language. If you're going to use C it's a very good idea to become familiar with ISO 9899 and what it does and does not cover.

Second: Be aware that even with a correctly-written program of this sort, scheduling work in a distributed system is not a trivial problem. You can enforce various simple sorts of ordering such as round-robin, but a multithreaded server (particularly using a thread-per-conversation model) is not likely to have predictable behavior.

On to the code.

```
    if(pthread_create(&client_thread,NULL,con,(void*) new)<0){
        perror("Error creating thread");
        return 1;
    }
    pthread_join(client_thread,NULL);
```

This code says:

1. Create a thread.
2. If that was successful, wait for it to terminate.

Your calling thread is going to block until the child thread is finished. You may as well not have created a thread in the first place.

But that's not the only problem here. Consider:

```
    new=malloc(1);
    *new=clientsoc;
```

`clientsock` is defined as an `int`. Are you really running on a platform where `sizeof(int) == 1`? That can only be true if `CHAR_BIT` is at least 16, which is ... unusual, shall we say. So likely here you have caused Undefined Behavior, and now anything can happen.

Passing hard-coded values to `malloc` is a Bad Thing. Do not do it. Try:

```
new=malloc(sizeof *new);
```

(Also, you might want to consider the name "new" as an identifier, in case you ever want to move this code to C++. Though frankly my preference is to never use a C++ implementation for C source; if you want C++, write C++.)

I haven't looked for other problems.